# Why does my thread stop after printing one line on its second run?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm using pthreads and I'm trying to run an infinite loop on the main thread. The loop is supposed to print out "Hello world!" 10 times, then create a separate thread that writes "Hello moon!" 10 times, and then start over.

For some reason the output of my program is (always):

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello moon!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello moon!
```

instead of running forever.

The code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEC_IN_NSEC(x) (x * 1000000000)

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *hello_moon(void *param);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t moon_tid;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    while(1) {
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("Hello world!\n");
            sleep(1);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_create(&moon_tid, NULL, hello_moon, NULL);
        pthread_join(moon_tid, NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
}

void* hello_moon(void *param)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_nsec = SEC_IN_NSEC(0.2); // 0.2 s in ns
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Hello moon!\n");
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

UPDATE: I commented out the sleep and nanosleep calls and ran it, then it loops as expected. I still want the delay between prints, however.

Comment: `struct timespec ts;` So, what is the value of `ts.tv_sec`?

Comment: I'm not a great Linux specialist, but here it gets stuck in `nanosleep(&ts, NULL);`

Comment: @KamilCuk Huh, that's odd. I set it to 0 and now it works. I thought it was defaulting to 0 because I had a very different version of the code before which worked perfectly and I didn't specify ts.tv_sec then either. Thanks!

Comment: @LostMikely `ts.tv_sec` hasn't been initialized, therefor you got undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wonder why it always worked once and then didn't on the second run. I have run the program so many times and gotten the same results.

Comment: @LostMikely _undefined behavour_ is undefined, it includes "apparently working fine". I think the program got stuck in `nanosleep` because the uninitialized values was huge.

Comment: Protip: That #define will fail if called with an expression such as `s+1`. Change to `SEC_IN_NSEC(x) ((x) * 1000000000)`

Comment: @klutt Oh, thought I had done that, but didn't know why it's done. Thank you!

Comment: @LostMikely General advice: Avoid macros. They are useful sometimes, but it's rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @KamilCuk in comments, you forget to initialize the `tv_sec` member:

```
struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec = 0; // add this, otherwise the member can be initialized with garbage
ts.tv_nsec = SEC_IN_NSEC(0.2); // 0.2 s in ns
```

also, you miss a header, add this at the beginning of the file:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <time.h>
```